# How to count green pixel in an image using Scala map reduce

Tags: image, scala, mapreduce

I am new to Scala programming, I am trying to count RGB values in an image using Scala (particularly green color). Below is the code to count only green pixels. My Question here is, How to achieve the same using Scala map reduce algorithms?

```
....
val lightGreen = new Color(0,255,0)
val darkGreen = new Color(0,100,0)

var ctrGreen = 0
var ctrTotal = 0
for (x <- 0 until w)
  for (y <- 0 until h) {
    val c = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y))
    if (isBetween(c, lightGreen,darkGreen)) {
      ctrGreen += 1
    }
    ctrTotal += 1;
  }

println("Green pixel count: " + ctrGreen)
println("Total pixel count: " + ctrTotal)

def isBetween(c: Color, c1: Color, c2: Color): Boolean = {
  c.getRed >= c1.getRed && c.getRed <= c2.getRed &&
    c.getBlue >= c1.getBlue && c.getBlue <= c2.getBlue && 
    c.getGreen <= c1.getGreen && c.getGreen >= c2.getGreen
}
```

How to count number of green pixels using map reduce algorithm in Scala?

Comment: Two last comparisons in `isBetween` are not consistent with four first ones. Also, do you mean MapReduce as in Hadoop or just standard `map` and `reduce` functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewritte it as follow :

```
val rangeX = (0 until w)
val rangeY = (0 until h)

val (greenPixels, allPixels) = (for ( x <- rangeX; y <- rangeY ) yield( (isGreen(x, y), 1) )).reduce( (a, b) => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2) )
```

Or in a more functional approach :

```
val (greenPixels, allPixels) = rangeX.flatMap( x => rangeY.map( y => (isGreen(x, y), 1) ) )
      .reduce( (a, b) => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2) )
```

Where isGreen is

```
def isGreen(x: Int, y: Int) =
{
  val c = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y))
  val isGreenAsInt = if( isBetween(c, lightGreen,darkGreen) ) 1 else 0
  isGreenAsInt
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot KyBe. will try this... it would be helpful if you share your email id.